# Java error adding totalcost

Tags: java

Please I need help.

1- In the method (`printOrderCos`), I am supposed to print out the `totalCost` of items from the `ArrayList` order. I defined the variable `totalCost` and count. Count is defined so that it works as an index that goes through each `element(item)` of the order `ArrayList` and then adds up the cost of each item to `totalCost`.

The problem that I encounter with the second method is with this line of code:

```
totalCost+=order.get(count);
```

it gives an error:

```
error: The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Item
```

Code:

```
public static ArrayList<Item> getOrder() { 
          ArrayList<Item> toBeReturned;
          toBeReturned = new ArrayList<Item>();
          Item item;
          item=A4Q1Util.getItem();
          while (item!=null) {
           toBeReturned.add(item);// it will all the items from A4Q1Util class to list
           item=A4Q1Util.getItem();   
          }
        return toBeReturned;
     }


         public static void printOrderCost(ArrayList<Item> order) { //prints the total        
          cost of the    order
              double totalCost;
              int count;
              totalCost=0;

              for (count=0;count<order.size();count++) {
              totalCost+=order.get(count);//intValue();
              }
              System.out.println("The total cost of your order is:");
         }

 class Item
{
  protected String description;
  protected int quantity;
  private double cost;

   public double getCost()
   {
      return this.cost;
   }

 public Item (String description, int quantity)
 {
   this.description = description;
   this.quantity = quantity;
 }

 } 

 class Coffee extends Item
{
  protected double cost;
  public Coffee (String description, int quantity)


 {
   super(description, quantity);
   cost = 4 ;
 }


}

 class Muffin extends Item
{
  protected double cost1Muffin;
  protected double cost2Muffin;
  protected double cost3Muffin;
  public Muffin (String description, int quantity)
 {
   super(description,quantity);
   cost1Muffin = 1;
   cost2Muffin = 0.75;
   cost3Muffin = 0.50;
 }



}


 class TimBits extends Item
{
 protected double cost;
 public TimBits (String description, int quantity)
 {
   super(description, quantity);
   cost = 0.25;
 }

}



class A4Q1Util  {
     private static ArrayList<Item> order;
     private static int count = 0;
     public static Item getItem() {
      Item item;

      if (order==null) {
       order = new ArrayList<Item>();

       order.add(new Muffin("Bran", 3));
       order.add(new Coffee("Latte", 1));
       order.add(new TimBits("Assorted", 24));
       order.add(new Muffin("Chocolate", 1));
       order.add(new Coffee("Decaf", 2));
       order.add(new TimBits("Chocolate", 12));
       order.add(new Muffin("PeanutButter", 2));
       order.add(new Muffin("Blueberry", 5));
      }

      item = null;
      if (count<order.size()) {
       item = order.get(count);
       count++;
      }
      {
      return item;
      }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't remove answered questions!

Answer (score 1):

As the error says.. `order` is an `ArrayList` that contains objects of type `Item`:

```
ArrayList<Item> order
          ↑
```

You're trying to add an `double` to an object of type `Item`. You can't do that.

One solution is to have a method that returns the `double` value of an `Item` and do something like:

```
totalCost += order.get(count).getDoubleValue();
```

Comment: Downvoter, can you please mention why? I don't see anything wrong with my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a Item object to a double.  Maybe you want something like

```
totalCost+=order.get(count).getValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a method in your `Item` class that returns the cost of this item.

```
public class Item{
   private double cost;
...
   public double getCost(){
      return this.cost;
   }
}
```

Then you can invokde `getCost()` on each Item like this:

```
totalCost+=order.get(count).getCost();
```

Answer (score 0):

As is, you are trying to add an Item to a double. You may wish to cast the item to a double by doing something like `(double)order.get(count)`.

Edit: the commenters are right - I misunderstood what Items were here. You need to add a method to Item that returns a double, then use that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this will work. `Item` is an object with its own properties (I'm guessing `type` and `price` based on the instantiation of `Item`s in the `getItem()` method). Instead of attempting to cast the object to a double, there should be a getter method that returns the cost of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide the details of the `Item` class, I can only assume what it looks like. Based on the lines

```
order.add(new Muffin("Bran", 3));
order.add(new Coffee("Latte", 1));
order.add(new TimBits("Assorted", 24));
...
```

I assume the `Item` class has a constructor like

```
public Item(String type, int price) {
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
}
```

When you are getting `Item` objects from the arraylist using `order.get(count)`, you are getting an object of type `Item`. This cannot be added to a primitive `double`. Some of the other answers suggest casting the `Item` to a `double`, but I do not believe that this will work, or even if it does, I don't think that is the correct way to go about adding it. The `Item` class should have a getter for the price. Something like

```
public int getPrice() {
    return this.price;
}
```

The line `totalCost+=order.get(count);//intValue();` suggests that there is already a method like that in your code. Use that method, and you should be able to add the `totalCost`